# »Reservierung für« oder »von«?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Ich spreche etwas Deutsch, aber es ist nicht mein Muttersprache. Welcher Satz ist richtig?

> Es gibt eine Reservierung von drei Zimmer.

oder

> Es gibt eine Reservierung für drei Zimmer.

Comment: "Es gibt eine Reservierung" ist quite awkward. I don't know your context, but probably "Ich habe drei Zimmer reserviert" is what you want to say. In which case you don't even need a preposition.

Comment: @Em1: Das stimmt nur, wenn der Sprecher selbst derjenige war, der die Zimmer reserviert hat. Wenn er der Sprecher einer dreiköpfigen Firmen-Delegation ist, die Reservierung aber eine Sekretärin gemacht hat, ist die Formulierung »Es gibt eine Reservierung für drei Zimmer (auf den Namen XY)« durchaus legitim.

Comment: @Em1: Andere Frage: Warum unterhältst du dich mit jemanden, von dem du weißt, das er Deutsch spricht, in einer Sprache, von der du nicht weist ob er sie beherrscht? Aus einem arabischen Namen und der Aussage »Deutsch ist nicht meine Muttersprache« (andere Informationen haben wir nicht) würde ich nicht schließen, dass Englisch eine Sprache ist, die der OP besser versteht als Deutsch.

Comment: "Es gibt eine Res. für 3 Zimmer" ist eher ein Satz, den ich von einem Hotelangestellten als Antwort erwarte.

Answer (score 5):

If you take 'von drei Zimmer**n**' it would mean that 3 rooms have reserved something.

> Es gibt eine Reservierung für drei Zimmer[...]

Is the correct phrase, possibly with the addition

> auf den Namen Khalil

Which would then mean "There is a reservervation for 3 rooms on the name Khalil.

Comment: Warum schreibst du in einem *Deutsch*-Forum auf eine in *Deutsch* gestellte Frage eine Antwort in einer Fremdsprache, von der du nicht weist, ob der Fragesteller sie beherrscht?

Comment: Ich denke weil ich es von SO gewohnt bin. Wenn es hier einen andere Höflichkeitsformen gibt, werde ich mich gern anpassen. Im Help Center steht geschrieben, dass beide Sprachen akzeptiert sind.

Comment: Ja, beide Sprachen werden akzeptiert. Aber wenn du keinerlei Veranlassung hast zu glauben, dass der Fragesteller English spricht, du aber sicher weißt, dass er Deutsch spricht (weil er genau das selbst geschrieben hat, noch dazu auf Deutsch), ist es klüger auf Deutsch zu antworten. Siehe auch: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/303/what-language-should-be-preferred-for-questions/830#830

Comment: Thank you all for your great help.I actually speak perfect American English ;-)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast selbst in dem meta Artikel steht drin man sollte auf English antworten. Macht auch viel mehr Sinn.

Comment: @Alex: Die verlinkte Meta-Antwort habe ich selbst geschrieben. Aus welchem Satz liest du heraus, dass man auf englisch antworten solle? Im Abschnitt »Language of answer« habe ich geschrieben: »*When ever possible try to give an answer **in the same language as the question** was asked.*« und darunter Bedingungen für Ausnahmen angeführt, in denen eine Abweichung von dieser Regel Sinn macht. Ich kann aber deine Behauptung nicht nachvollziehen, dass es mehr Sinn macht, auf eine deutsche Frage auf englisch als auf deutsch zu antworten. Ich sehe das als sehr unsinnig an.

Comment: Wäre es nicht sinnvoller dieses Thema im Chat zu klären, anstatt die Kommentarsektion damit zu verschmutzen?

Comment: Serv Recht hast du, hier mein letzter Kommentar zu diesem Thema. @HubertSchölnast ich rede nicht von Ihrer Antwort, sondern vom Thread. In der akzeptierten Antwort sind einige schlüssige Begründungen aufgeführt, dessen Meinung ich teile. Ham was jetzt?

Answer (score 2):

Da „reservieren“ transitiv ist, ist

> Reservierung von drei Zimmern

oder

> Reservierung dreier Zimmer

sicher nicht falsch, aber

> Reservierung für drei Zimmer

ist auch gebräuchlich. Es kommt auf den Satz an, was natürlicher klingt.

> Ich habe eine Reservierung von drei Zimmern.

klingt in der Tat merkwürdig, während

> Nach der Reservierung von drei Zimmern musste ich noch einen Flug buchen.

ok ist und *für* hier irritierend wäre.

Answer (score 0):

Das tangiert deine Frage (»welcher Satz ist richtig?«) natürlich nur marginal – aber als wesentlich schöner empfinde ich folgende Varianten:

> Ich habe drei Zimmer reserviert.
>
> Drei Zimmer wurden (auf Ihren Namen) reserviert.

Das vermeidet sowohl den etwas holprig empfundenen Nominalstil wie auch *es gibt* als Subjekt-Prädikat-Kombination.

Wenn du unbedingt bei einer von den beiden Formulierungen bleiben möchtest, würde ich dir *für drei Zimmer* empfehlen, wie es meine Vorredner schon getan haben.